# Jasper Report with more than one page

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm currently using the report to print out the information of all the employees using the same format. 
For example, here is the employee table in my database.

```
EmployeeID  NAME  AGE
----------------------
     1      Tom    28
     2      John   30
     3      Tony   32
```

I just want to print out the information of the employees using the same format whenever there is other employees in the table. (first employee in first page, second  in the second page.....)
Is there any way like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PageBreak for each row so you can have a page

To implement this solution:

- add the table component to your report
- open the DataSet associated with this report and add to it the Group
- set Group expression to

  (int)($V{REPORT_COUNT} - 1)
- check 'Start on a new page' property

see the link for more detail 
http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-how-introduce-page-break-after-pre-defined-number-rows-table-component

Comment: thanks for your solution! However, if I want to use a table designed by myself instead of using the table element, is there any other way? Since the record showed is not aligned in one single row.

Comment: the important is to use the group for page break the conditions can be different this is a jrxml with page break based on a group [link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/wiki_attachments/datasourcereport_285.jrxml)

Comment: Thanks! I have found the solution. It's the problem with my sql.